# CORS XSL with Chrome

Tags: javascript, xml, google-chrome, xslt

Short:

**XSLT is applied to an XML and I want to load another XML using `document(http://...)`, from another domain than the XSL and the original XML. I added CORS headers to the server and it works on Firefox, not on Chrome. Why, and how to fix that?**

---

Complete case:

I first tried CORS request using html5Rocks example. So I have an html document, at `http://localhost/cors.html` containing this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>

        </title>
        <script>
            function createCORSRequest(method, url)
            {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                if ("withCredentials" in xhr)
                {
                    // Check if the XMLHttpRequest object has a "withCredentials" property.
                    // "withCredentials" only exists on XMLHTTPRequest2 objects.
                    xhr.open(method, url, true);
                }
                else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined")
                {
                    // Otherwise, check if XDomainRequest.
                    // XDomainRequest only exists in IE, and is IE's way of making CORS requests.
                    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
                    xhr.open(method, url);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Otherwise, CORS is not supported by the browser.
                    xhr = null;
                }
                return xhr;
            }

            function go()
            {
                console.log('go!');
                var url = 'http://cors1.localhost/cors-data.xml';
                var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', url);
                if (!xhr)
                {
                    throw new Error('CORS not supported');
                }
                xhr.onload = function()
                {
                    var responseText = xhr.responseText;
                    var responseXml = xhr.responseXML;
                    console.log(responseXml);
                    // process the response.
                };
                xhr.onerror = function()
                {
                    console.log('There was an error!');
                };
                xhr.send();
            }
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', go, false);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Works fine on firefox: the XHR object sends the CORS request, and it's well handled by both browser and server, thanks to the following server's .htaccess file:

```
Header  set Access-Control-Allow-Origin         "*"
Header  set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials    "true"
Header  set Access-Control-Allow-Methods        "OPTIONS, GET, POST"
Header  set Access-Control-Allow-Headers        "Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control"
```

Now, I test it on Chrome... No problem, it works fine too ☺
In both browsers, the console displays the content of the XHR response (its `responseXml`), so I assume that the server is well configured (isn't it?).

Now, I have a XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="CORS.xsl"?>

    <cors source="http://cors1.localhost/CORS-data.xml"/>
```

And the XSLT applied on it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/cors">
        <xsl:variable name="cors" select="document(@source)/cors"/>
        <p>
            <xsl:text>CORS-data.xml (</xsl:text>
            <a href="{@source}">
                <xsl:value-of select="@source"/>
            </a>
            <xsl:text>): </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$cors"/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So the XSLT should load an external document (`http://cors1.localhost/CORS-data.xml`) and displays its content (`<xsl:value-of select="$cors"/>`). It actually does it well in Firefox, but not in Chrome, where console says:

`Unsafe attempt to load URL http://cors1.localhost/CORS.xsl from frame with URL http://localhost/CORS.xml. Domains, protocols and ports must match.`

And page results in:

`CORS-data.xml (http://cors1.localhost/CORS-data.xml):`

There should be the document()-loaded XML content (a simple 'ok') after the `:` but it's void.

I saw several subjects about this kind of problem, but they are about `file:///` protocol, not about `http://`. I can understand that `file:///` XSLT are disallowed for security reasons, but I don't get

**why Chrome's CORS works with javascript's XHR but fails with XSLT's `document()` function?** And how to fix that?

Answer (score -1):

Chrome does not allow localhost as origin, you should try start your Chrome with --allow-file-access-from-files and --disable-web-security flags.

Comment: --allow-file-access-from-files is useless, I'll check for the ``localhost`` domain thing.

Comment: ``localhost`` or ``cors1.cors`` that redirects to ``127.0.0.1`` (using windows host file) doesn't change Chrome's CORS behaviour. I'm not looking for a way to cut-off all security, but to use CORS in XSL ``document()``.

Comment: I have a similar problem, my application is built using Angular 7. I am making an ajax call to a BPMS server which works fine in IE but I have a CORS error in Chrome. However when I copy the ajax url to the Chrome browser I have all the data. Can anyone help?